# Spring Roo Show ID in list.jspx

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I have the following in my list.jspx file.

```
<table:table data="${tests}" id="l_com_mtc_test_Test" path="/tests" typeIdFieldName="testId" z="rVizJj8FpPQ5KoK8/JRRK464fR8=">
     <table:column id="c_com_mtc_test_Test_name" property="name" z="FdtZTAmJsb4/B16zRGrrO8e2pT8="/>
</table:table>
```

I want to show to id for the table (specifically the testId reference in typeIDFieldName). I haven't had any luck inserting my own table:column, perhaps I'm doing something wrong, any advice?